# Leibniz formula for determinants even/odd?

Tags: permutations, determinant

I am trying to get my head around the Leibniz formula for this $3 \times 3$ determinant. I know that

So for $n=3$ we get $$\det(A) = a_{1,1}a_{2,2}a_{3,3} - a_{1,1}a_{2,3}a_{3,2} - a_{1,3}a_{2,2}a_{3,1} - a_{1,2}a_{2,1}a_{3,3} + a_{1,2}a_{2,3}a_{3,1} + a_{1,3}a_{2,1}a_{3,2}$$

But I don't know how we work out the signs in each case above? Could someone show me how? I know the sign is $+$ when the permutation is even but how is $a_{1,1}a_{2,2}a_{3,3}$ even but $a_{1,2}a_{2,1}a_{3,3}$ is odd?

Comment: both of them have negative signs in what you wrote.

Comment: Did you even look at the indices properly? There is a minus sign in front of $a_{13}a_{22}a_{31}$.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, corrected now

Comment: There are many different ways to find the [sign of a permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation). The formular $\prod_{i<j} \frac{i-j}{\sigma(i)-\sigma(j)}$, counting inversions, using cycle length in the disjoint cycle decomposition, counting how many transpositions you need to decompose $\sigma$ as a product of such, … Pick the one you like best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative odd/even property is the parity of the number of inversions. An inversion of a permutation $\sigma$ is defined to be the set $$Inv(\sigma)=\{(i,j):i<j\text{ and }\sigma_i>\sigma _j\}.$$
So, in your case $Inv(321)=\{(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)\}$ because $3>1$ and $3>2$ and $2>1$ is odd because it has $3$ inversions and $Inv(213)=\{(1,2)\}$ (the only one is $2>1$) also has $1$ so is odd. In general, the sign of a permutation $\sigma$ is $(-1)^{|Inv(\sigma)|}.$

Comment: I see! Thank you!

Comment: @JamesO'dare You are welcome!